# Fix OpenCV Demo for running with success the code of the project

Tags: android, opencv, feature-detection

I have downloaded the following OpenCV demo for image detection, unfortunately as I explain in the issues it does not compile in Android Studio 3.4 after solving the new dependencies it throws me the undefined reference error to an openCV function written in C++

Thank you in advance for your help.

https://github.com/michaeltroger/feature-matching-native/issues/2